# Creating a .txt File and Changing its Directory in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a .txt file with this:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

And I am writing something in it. But I want to also determine its directory. For example, my workspace is under C, but I want to create .txt under D. How can I do that?

Comment: Direction!! Do you mean Directory ?

Comment: Give the absolute path of the File.It will directly get created inside that directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:/out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

When give the path "out.txt" as argument, file is created in the current directory. If you want to create file in another location you have to give it's absolute path as argument.
Note that in windows directory separator is `\` (backslash) and if you're using windows path should be `"D:\\out.txt"`. Why 2 slashes? because in Java slash is a special symbol (for example `\n` is new line symbol) and should be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\out.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean `Directory` not `Direction`, as pointed out by codaddict. 
You can take a look at the [FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29) if you want to move the file.

If you want to create another copy (meaning 2 files), just do something like so:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```